# Remove AlamofireImage responseImage from main thread

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

Simply speaking i'm attempting to download an image on a server using `AlamofireImage` and it appears that the DataRequest extension responsible for this returns the content on the main thread.

This is problematic because it does inevitably lock the UI while it continues to process.

See the attached image, the breakpoint halts the execution of the main thread (on the left)

[image: Response on main thread]

How can I migrate this DataRequest to use an OperationQueue that's not main?

Comment: perhaps @cnoon would be able to offer some insight?

Comment: I think that the filter function is the thing that is locking the main thread. I think you should try to apply the filter on a different thread. Good luck!

Comment: Yes that is the culprit. Though this doesn't answer the full question, i'd like to have the whole responseImage callback on a sub thread. @timaktimak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an optional queue parameter to the responseImage function so that an arbitrary `DispatchQueue` could be used to run `completionHandler` on. [image]

Here is the fork:

```
pod 'AlamofireImage', :git => 'https://github.com/timaktimak/AlamofireImage.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Edit: it was merged in, so AlamofireImage now has the functionality of calling the completion block on a custom `DispatchQueue`.

Hope it helps!